# Error with converting access query to SQL Server 2012 query

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access

I am converting queries from Access 1010 into SQL Server 2012. 
The following is part of a query

```
Count(Stats.SessionNumber) AS TotalSessions, Sum(Stats.Duration) AS TotalDuration, 
Round([TotalDuration]/[TotalSessions],1) AS AverageDuration
```

I get the following Error:
Invalid column name 'TotalDuration'.
Invalid column name 'TotalSessions'.

Does the alias of TotalDuration and TotalSessions need to be handled differently in SQL Server
and if so how?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this....

```
SELECT  TotalSessions
       ,TotalDuration
       ,Round([TotalDuration]/[TotalSessions],1) AS AverageDuration
FROM (
        SELECT  Count([Stats].SessionNumber) AS TotalSessions
               , SUM([Stats].Duration) AS TotalDuration
        FROM Table_Name
     ) A
```

Answer (score 1):

In SQLServer, you can't work on an alias you just assigned. You either need to use a sub query, or reuse your `SUM` and `COUNT`.

Re-use:

```
Count(Stats.SessionNumber) AS TotalSessions, Sum(Stats.Duration) AS TotalDuration, 
Round(Sum(Stats.Duration)/Count(Stats.SessionNumber),1) AS AverageDuration
```

Subquery:

```
SELECT TotalSessions, TotalDuration, Round(TotalDuration/TotalSessions,1) AS AverageDuration
FROM
(
  SELECT RCount(Stats.SessionNumber) AS TotalSessions, Sum(Stats.Duration) AS TotalDuration, 
  FROM yourTableName
 ) subquery
```